# XmlWriter comlex usage with a XmlReader

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I im going to read file by xmlReader and insert a child elements into this object by XmlWriter and save the output. How i can parse data between this two classes? I know that SimpleXml is already exists and makes it easy. but i have a huge amount of the data and i need to make it faster then SimpleXml can. It is only teory and i havnt code yet, i need only to get answer only by these qwestions: 
Is creating two objects reader/writer and their work Is faster then similar via SimpleXml ?
How does it possible to use xmlReader object and parse data parts into XmlWriter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLWriter` is not only faster than `SimpleXML`, but also takes less memory. Especially when you need to handle large amounts of data (as you do), you should use `XMLWriter` as with larger data speed really starts to matter.

Of course, you can have a `XMLReader` and a `XMLWriter` at the same time. And you would do it just as you wrote: read from the `XMLReader` and write it immediately to the `XMLWriter`.

**edit:** I found some nice statistics (and also a code sample) [here](http://p0l0.binware.org/index.php/2011/07/04/simplexml-vs-xmlwriter-vs-dom/). Reading that, I also learned that SimpleXML takes less memory than the XMLWriter, which surprises me a little...so my initial statement seems to be only 50% true. Faster: yes, less memory: no.

Comment: That's because the test makes XMLWriter writes in memory:  `$xml->openMemory();`, reducing its benefits.